The url in my react application is updating but the component is not loading
I am building a web application using react as frontend and firebase for backend. in the login page, after user hit the login button the toastify message displays "login successful", I want to navigate to /dashboard after the message, but only the url is updating from "/login" to "/dashboard" but the Dashboard component is not loading.
        e.preventDefault();
       
        try {
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
            
            
            // Immediately set the user sign-in state and store UID
            setIsSignIn(true);
            const user = auth.currentUser;
            console.log(user)
            if (user) {
                localStorage.setItem("uid", user.uid);
            }

            toast.success("login successful")
            
            setTimeout(()=>{
              navigate("/dashboard")
            },5000)
        
            console.log("login successfull...")
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error(error.message);
        }
        
    }

the above code is for handling the event after user enter login button.

Please edit the question to show the code for the dashboard component, in addition to the code that should make it visible when the URL path changes to /dashboard.  We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves to see what it actually does.  Right now we have no idea what will happen when navigate("/dashboard") is executed.
